# Why are the point incentives removed for review or edit after receiving 'X' points

Tags: discussion

Suggestion: To continue awarding points for review and edit tasks.

After certain levels of points you no longer receive points for completing task, such as `edit` and `reviews`. Where is the incentive to continue doing these tasks after you've reached those point levels?

Comment: The incentive is you are helping improve the quality of the posts on the site.  We don't want low quality posts hanging around, improve them and you help make the site better.

Comment: I would argue the reason most people participate on this site is because it is gamified. Meaning that people are going to pay first attention to what increases their score before doing things out of the kindness of their hearts.

Comment: Maybe at first, sure, but at least for me and probably others, I participated to **help** people. That involved posting the best possible answer that I could,  also improving questions/answers as needed, so people with the same question could find a solution.

Comment: The question is still, why remove the incentive?

Comment: What would you propose as an extra incentive to get people to go even farther?

Comment: continue to give points, have more awards for completing those tasks (metals, hats, and other) Right now I get notifications to review tasks, but since it doesn't effect me in any ways I focus on answering other questions instead of assisting in monitoring content

Comment: @SethMcClaine There are already badges for reviewing.  If you don't find any benefit in reviewing, then you don't have to do it; it's not mandatory to participate in the site.  Find other things that are rewarding to you, like answering questions, etc.  There are already issues with users robo-reviewing to get badges, we're not going to add rep to reviews because ti'll just make the problem worse.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there's hard data or statistics to support it, but from my observations the gamification of edits isn't really very helpful in the grand scheme.

Just sayin that, generally speaking, those that edit just for rep tend to make lots of small edits because their goal is really the little rep boost. While those that edit for more altruistic reasons tend to put a little more time and effort in.

I'm not saying that the rep bonus should be removed altogether, it does help some people learn to edit... But limiting it helps people to edit for the right reasons.

Comment: I get what you're saying, I think you should be rewarded for good edits and possibly negative for bad. I think all edits should still be reviewed, and there should be reward for completing that task. What they have done with putting in the "are you paying attention test" is also good. But what keeps me coming back and participating, besides researching my own questions and learning from others question, is the part that i am being noticed for what I have done.

Comment: @SethMcClaine to me, the fact your name appears as the editor is credit to you being noticed. If you want PURE rep for your actions, then take actions that give rep.... it's simple. Edits won't give rep, because you are not reviewed anymore. If you want rep rep rep rep, just don't do these. I feel it's kinda sad if ALL you can take from such a great site is "I got 2K rep, YAY!", but I'm not one to tell you how to spend your time here :).